# Can a Judge ask for a manifest injustice then dismiss the motion?

Tags: criminal-law, rules-of-court, florida, process, due-process

First, a Pro Se POST CONVICTION RELIEF was filed for an issue relating to tampering with evidence (a Joseph Graves issue) and the judge responded with:

> Since Defendant is seeking to withdraw her plea of guilty on the basis
> of newly discovered evidence, she will only be allowed to do so upon a
> showing of "manifest injustice.”

Since the circuit court judge didn't agree, we had a professional appeal filed for the same issue and amended the appeal with a second sentence manipulation issue. 1.5 years later, the professional appeal was Per Curiam Affirmed by the District Court of Appeals. No opinion was given and we don't even think anyone read it.

We then file another professional Post Conviction Relief based on the facts of the record to provide the judge with what he asked for: a "manifest injustice". The manifest injustice was sentence manipulation and cruel and unusual punishment.

The circuit court issued an ORDER DISMISSING DEFENDANTS UNTITLED MOTION AS UNTIMELY. Again, we don't think anyone read it even though we cited the Judges request for a showing of a manifest injustice and titled the sentencing manipulation issue "**MANIFEST INJUSTICE**", emphasized using bold and capitals.

[Post Conviction Relief Document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_xA4rZ8j1ujSmcwU0JyOHh2TXM/view?usp=sharing)

Can the judge ask for a manifest injustice then dismiss the motion? What should the defendant do next? Can we ask for a thorough review and opinion because she was providing what the judge asked for? Is the lower court required to read appeals and post convictions before filing a motion?

Comment: If you're referencing a real world case could you provide an explicit reference so anyone interested in answering can examine the full situation instead of relying on your confusing summary?

Comment: What was affirmed in the professional appeal?

Comment: @Dawn, hopefully the edits will answer your question. Let me know if you need more information

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say the appeal was affirmed. Usually "affirmed" means that the appeals court agrees with the lower court's holding and that the petitioner's appeal was unsuccessful. Is that what happened?

Comment: Yes, the District Court affirmed the Lower Court's holding regarding the Joseph Grave's tampering with evidence issue. However, an additional issue was raised that the lower court was unaware of during the appeal and that was the sentence manipulation issue

Comment: Back to the question, the judge asked for a showing of manifest injustice, then, when one was provided, dismissed the post as untimely. What would be the next step? We would like at least for it to be read by the judge and his opinion.

Comment: @feetwet I can't offer an explicit reference but I am willing to sanitize the Post Conviction Relief and post it. Will that work?

Comment: I imagine that would *help*.  I really can't follow or make sense of the snippets in your current question.  And you shouldn't trust yourself to have presented every relevant detail.  (Granted, there's a practical limit to what you can post in-line.  If you can sanitize filings and post links to them hosted elsewhere that would be best.)

Comment: @feetwet Okay, I've added the sanitized Post Conviction Relief document as a link to the question. Let me know if it needs further sanitization. It's a beautiful piece of work IMO

Comment: A judge stating that you failed to do something you had to do is not necessarily inviting you to do it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The judge told her that she is _'**allowed** to do so [withdrawal her guilty plea] upon a showing of "manifest injustice.”'_ The judge is stating that the possibility to withdrawal the guilty plea still exists, right? We have interpreted this as an invitation and still available option to provide an injustice.

Comment: @Breakskater No. He's telling her what the rule is, not indicating that that option is still available to her. The "will" refers to what will happen in the later analysis in that very ruling, not what might happen in future proceedings.

Comment: Okay @DavidSchwartz. The rule then states that if she has newly discovered evidence then she can withdrawal her guilty plea upon showing an injustice.

Comment: @Breakskater Right, but there was no newly-discovered evidence. All the evidence was introduced in the motion in which the judge found you hadn't showed manifest injustice. Deciding to make new arguments for why there was manifest injustice is not newly-discovered evidence.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The newly-discovered evidence was the officer's sentence manipulation which was recently discovered in the police report and overlooked by the public defender, defendant, and judge before sentencing (pre-trial, plea bargaining, etc).

Comment: Your chance to use the sentencing manipulation as newly-discovered evidence to show manifest injustice came and went with the ruling that found that you didn't show manifest injustice using that evidence and then when you lost your appeal on that ruling. From then on, it's not newly-discovered anymore and even if you can show manifest injustice, it won't help. Newly-discovered evidence is only newly-discovered once.

Comment: The manifest injustice was never raised in the lower court. The not showing a manifest injustice the judge was referring to was the tampering with evidence issue

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've glossed over the core problem here, which a trial lawyer might confirm: **The responsive motion was ruled untimely.** That's a pretty big obstacle to surmount. I.e., it doesn't matter how good your filing is; if it's untimely it doesn't merit consideration.

The only ways I know of to advance an appeal at such a point are:

1. File a motion/petition for reconsideration/relief.  The grounds for reconsideration of an order depend substantially on the nuances of the case, and can vary by venue, but they typically include:

   1. Mistakes of law or rules (by the court)
   2. Newly discovered evidence
   3. Misconduct or misrepresentation by another party (including your counsel)
   4. Excusable neglect
   5. Extenuating circumstances or other compelling justifications for the untimeliness of the filing.  (E.g., the appellant was held hostage incommunicado during the response period, and filed as soon as freed.)
2. Appeal the Order of Dismissal.

(I would also note that if I had paid a lawyer to file a motion, the motion was dismissed as untimely, and the lawyer hadn't given me adequate warning that it might be untimely under the rules of procedure; then I would take my lawyer to task and put the onus on him to fix the problem promptly, diligently, and at his expense.)

---

Amendment, having reviewed the Motion for Postconviction Relief:

It looks like there are three substantive questions:

1. Is *State v. Steadman* binding on that court, and does it say what that Motion says it does? If so then *all* court officers made a mistake of law.
2. Was the sentence based on an incorrect calculation of the drug weight? If so, then that represents a substantive mistake of fact warranting the court's reconsideration. But:
3. If a defendant accepts a plea bargain, can any of these questions be raised in court? I would hope so, but (cynically) not be surprised if the answer is *no*.

Comment: thanks. I think we will try #1 first because the sentence manipulation was (newly discovered) and overlooked by the defendant and court, (misconduct) was present by the officer, waiting for another appeal's decision before starting this post (extenuating circumstance and excusable neglect). I believe those are sufficient reasons for petitioning the untimely and for filing the post conviction relief?

Comment: @Breakskater - *I* think so, but ultimately it's what a judge thinks that matters!

Comment: that's unfortunate but I agree

Comment: @Breakskater I don't think it was overlooked. The court just ruled that you didn't show that it amounted to manifest injustice. You lost your appeal of that ruling, right? Isn't it now law of the case that the sentencing manipulation didn't constitute manifest injustice?

Comment: That issue, sentencing manipulation, was never heard by the lower court and no opinion by the court of appeals; I doubt the issue was even read

Answer (score 0):

I read it till page 4 only, following is my summarized version till pg 4 with inputs:-

*State v. Steadman* , holds that defendant does not have the right for downward departure sentencing but I believe **she definitely have the right to be considered for downward departure sentencing (DDS) , whether she gets it or not thats a different scenario.**

She's not asking for DDS as a matter of right because of sentencing manipulation by officer's conduct but to the least her matter is worthy of consideration because:

1. sentencing manipulation by officer took place
2. her counsel failed to address this critical issue
3. plea bargaining happened in ignorance of above two things
4. had she known before plea bargaining that sentencing manipulation could bring her reduced sentence, she might have chosen to go for trial instead of plea bargaining.

I agree with the reasoning given by judge w.r.t corrupt former employee, that doesn't help defendant's case. Can't see any injustice arising from this employee being corrupt.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you read the post in its entirety? I would love to hear your feedback regarding the other issues: punishing end users as traffickers, disproportionate sentencing, active ingredient weight vs aggregate weight.